# Paypal REST API 403 ERROR

Tags: java, api, rest, servlets, paypal

I'm trying to integrate a paypal payment to my JavaEE web application.
Every time I try to make a payment, it throw a 403 Error.

Here is the servlet I'm using:

```
@WebServlet(name="PaypalPayment", urlPatterns={"/paypal-payment.html"})
public class Paypal_Payment extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    OAuthTokenCredential token;
    String accessToken;
    APIContext apiContext;

    Map<String, String> sdkConfig = new HashMap<String, String>();
    sdkConfig.put("mode", "sandbox");
    sdkConfig.put("service.EndPoint", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com");
    sdkConfig.put("client_id", Constantes.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);
    sdkConfig.put("secret", Constantes.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET);

    try{
      token = new OAuthTokenCredential(Constantes.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID, Constantes.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET, sdkConfig);
      accessToken = token.getAccessToken();
      apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
      apiContext.setConfigurationMap(sdkConfig);
      Amount amount = new Amount();
      amount.setCurrency("EUR");
      amount.setTotal("25");

      Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
      transaction.setDescription("Creating Payment");   
      transaction.setAmount(amount);
      List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
      transactions.add(transaction);
      Payer payer = new Payer();
      payer.setPaymentMethod("paypal");
      Payment payment = new Payment();
      payment.setIntent("sale");
      payment.setPayer(payer);
      payment.setTransactions(transactions);

      RedirectUrls redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
      redirectUrls.setCancelUrl("http://example.com/a-vos-cas-JSP/paypal-payment.html");
      redirectUrls.setReturnUrl("http://example.com/a-vos-cas-JSP/paypal-payment.html");

      payment.setRedirectUrls(redirectUrls);
      Payment createdPayment = payment.create(apiContext);
      System.out.println("createdPayment : " + createdPayment);
    }catch(PayPalRESTException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    getServletContext().getNamedDispatcher(Constantes.VUE_PAYPAL_RESPONSE).forward(request, response);
  }
}
```

here is the console output:

> 14:26:15,550 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) curl command: 
>   14:26:15,551 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) curl -v
>   'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \ 14:26:15,552 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "Authorization: Basic
>   QWJHQTFSQXVpeVA0RDVvQmt5d1o3dTBCanJJWkt0dm9CaVhTcDZ0QWFINlM4LXRFdzByX2hyRzNfbUZMOkVBRmhVQkJkZWRqTmJfTXV6SlNpbVI1YnY3SThQVzdwUldibGQ2aE9seThMZlNnRlhhbS1LaHJtRVZmZA=="
>   \ 14:26:15,552 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "User-Agent:
>   PayPalSDK/paypal-core-java 1.5.0
>   (lang=Java;v=1.7.0_55;bit=64;os=Mac_OS_X 10.9.2)" \ 14:26:15,553 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "Accept: application/json" \
>   14:26:15,553 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -d
>   'grant_type=client_credentials' 14:26:16,878 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) curl command:  14:26:16,879 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) curl -v
>   'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment' \ 14:26:16,879
>   INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "Authorization: Bearer
>   A015iJYDQHdb7TJXzJzVIW-eSm1lP8NObGmlJkTzx2wVREo" \ 14:26:16,879 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "User-Agent:
>   PayPalSDK/rest-sdk-java 0.9.0 (lang=Java;v=1.7.0_55;bit=64;os=Mac_OS_X
>   10.9.2)" \ 14:26:16,880 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "PayPal-Request-Id: 7b42030f-9b96-4027-9257-0c1311082fa2" \
>   14:26:16,880 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) -H "Content-Type:
>   application/json" \ 14:26:16,880 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)
>   -d '{ 14:26:16,880 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   "intent": "sale", 14:26:16,880 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   "payer":
>   { 14:26:16,881 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)
>   "payment_method": "paypal" 14:26:16,881 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   }, 14:26:16,881 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   "transactions": [ 14:26:16,881 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)     { 14:26:16,881 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)       "amount": { 14:26:16,882 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)         "currency": "EUR", 14:26:16,882 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)         "total": "25" 14:26:16,882
>   INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)       }, 14:26:16,882 INFO 
>   [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)       "description": "Creating
>   Payment" 14:26:16,882 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)     }
>   14:26:16,883 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   ], 14:26:16,883
>   INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   "redirect_urls": {
>   14:26:16,883 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)     "return_url":
>   "http://example.com/a-vos-cas-JSP/paypal-response.html",
>   14:26:16,883 INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)     "cancel_url":
>   "http://example.com/a-vos-cas-JSP/paypal-cancel.html" 14:26:16,884
>   INFO  [stdout] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)   } 14:26:16,884 INFO  [stdout]
>   (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) }' 14:26:17,909 Grave [class
>   com.paypal.core.HttpConnection] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6) Error code :
>   403 with response : {"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","message":"Access
>   token does not have required
>   scope","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","debug_id":"e066fbac38f41"}
>   14:26:17,911 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-6)
>   com.paypal.core.rest.PayPalRESTException: Error code : 403 with
>   response : {"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","message":"Access token
>   does not have required
>   scope","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING","debug_id":"e066fbac38f41"}

So, there is a message saying that the scope could not be found, but I was not able to get any information about this error. I think I missed something in this servlet, but I can't find what. Any help would be appreciated :D
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The answer is contained in this response:

```
{"name":"REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING",
 "message":"Access token does not have required scope",
 "information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#REQUIRED_SCOPE_MISSING",
 "debug_id":"e066fbac38f41"}
```

There's some attribute in your app's configuration that's missing. Your best bet is to contact support with the `debug_id` listed. They can help get your account configured correctly.